# Verificar informaron de variable en arreglo (in array) PHP

Tags: php, sql, array

buenos días espero me puedan orientar con esta duda.

De que manera puedo verificar que el texto de una variable que obtengo por GET, este en un arreglo que obtengo desde una consulta a base de datos.

```
// Variable // 
VarLine = $_GET['line'];
$QueryvalidLines= "SELECT * FROM psb_smt.psb_lineas
WHERE category != 'FINAL ASSEMBLY'";
$RsltQueryValid = mysqli_query($con,$QueryvalidLines);

while($row = $RsltQueryValid->fetch_assoc()) {
    $validLines= array($row["name"]);
    if ( in_array($VarLine ,$validLines) ){
       echo "Si existe";
    }else{
       echo "No existe";
    }
}
?>
```

**En la consulta que hago arriba solo obtengo la siguiente informacion:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo intente de la manera que les mostre pero no funciona.

De la forma que me funciona es declarado el arreglo de manera estatica.

```
$validLines=array("Linea 01","Linea 02","Linea 03","Linea 04","Linea 05","Linea 06");
```

Comment: Pero entonces carga los resultados a un array para que sean analizados.

Comment: detalla si el texto que recibes  del GET será el índice o el valor en tu array..

Comment: El valor de GET solo son "Linea 01" , "Linea 02" hasta "Linea 06" si el valor es diferente a eso deberia redirigir a "index.php" por eso mismo los quiero comparar con esa consulta que hice.

Comment: todos o solo uno??? tengo mas dudas ahora cual es el contenido de $_GET['line'] ???

Comment: El contenido del GET es eso "Linea 01", "Linea 02" hasta "Linea 06" a travez de una liga localhost/subcarpeta/line.php?line=Linea%2005 el punto es que si de alguna forma se pusiera otro dato en "line" pues me saque de la pagina ya que no esta dada de alta en mi base de datos que por lo mismo se hizo la consulta, para que se compare ese dato del GET con el de la consulta.

Comment: `GET['line']` contiene un solo dato: ejem: `"Linea 01"` o varios datos concatenados por coma `"Linea 01", "Linea 02"` ?

Comment: Solo un dato, asi como puse en el comentario como se ve en esa URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Primero*** esta linea esta mal (te comiste el `$`):

```
VarLine = $_GET['line'];
```

debe ser:

```
$VarLine = $_GET['line'];
```

***Segundo*** para validar debes seguir este ejemplo

```
<?php

$VarLine = 'Linea 01'; // es igual a $_GET['line']
    
//y tu array :
    
$validLines=array("Linea 01","Linea 02","Linea 03","Linea 04","Linea 05","Linea 06");
    
//con esto lo validas:
    
if ( in_array($VarLine ,$validLines) ){
    echo "Si existe";
}else{
    header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
}
```

El output es:

```
Si existe
```

O te redirecciona a tu `index.php`

[Link de la prueba](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b6WL)

**Tercero:** Otra forma de Validar si Existe es mediante la misma consulta:

**Nota:** según tu ejemplo implementar esto es inseguro, ya que esta abierto a inyección de código en la consulta, solo es seguro si implementas [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) y [bindValue](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).

```
<?php

$VarLine = 'Linea 01'; // es igual a $_GET['line']

$QueryvalidLines= "SELECT * FROM psb_smt.psb_lineas WHERE category != 'FINAL ASSEMBLY' AND name='".$VarLine."';"; //este es el primer cambio
$RsltQueryValid = mysqli_query($con,$QueryvalidLines);

//este es el segundo cambio
if($RsltQueryValid->num_rows > 0){
    echo "Si existe";
}else{
     header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
}
```

***Cuarta:*** Opción evadiendo la inyección de código con mas código PHP:

```
<?php
$VarLine = 'Linea 01'; // es igual a $_GET['line']
$QueryvalidLines= "SELECT * FROM psb_smt.psb_lineas
WHERE category != 'FINAL ASSEMBLY'";
$RsltQueryValid = mysqli_query($con,$QueryvalidLines);
$validLines=[]; // Cambio esto se inicializa un array:
while($row = $RsltQueryValid->fetch_assoc()) {
    $validLines[]= $row["name"]; // Cambio esto llenamos el array.
}

//la comprobación se hace afuera

if ( in_array($VarLine ,$validLines) ){
    echo "Si existe";
}else{
    header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
}
```

Comment: De esta manera si me funciona asi lo tengo, pero lo que quiero lograr es que los datos de "$validLines" sean datos que obtenga de la consulta que hice a  la base de datos en el post.

Comment: no es mas fácil si consultas si existe en la base de datos??? déjame agregar un ejemplo

Comment: Es cierto, desde la consulta es mas facil XD, gracias.♥

Comment: @EduardoMX mira las tercer y cuarta opción en mi post.

Comment: @EduardoMX ten cuidado mira la actualización..

Comment: Probe la cuarta opcion pero no me funciono, de hecho asi es como lo estaba haciendo yo pero no me funciona

Comment: @EduardoMX al decir que no te funciona tienes que decir que te sale a mi si me funciona XD, pero lo tube que modificar, vuelve a revisar.

Comment: simplemente me redirige

Comment: @ya probaste la ultima actualización??????

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130174/discussion-between-francisco-nunez-todo-poderoso-and-eduardomx).

Answer (score 1):

Tu código debería de verse de esta manera :

```
while($row = $RsltQueryValid->fetch_array()) {
    if ($row[1]==$VarLine) {
       echo "Si existe";
    }
    }else{
       echo "No existe";
    }
}
```

Donde `$row[0]` son los valores que estan en tu columna `name`, por lo que si el valor de tu variable `VarLine` existe en algun registro de tu columna `name` es que existe.

Piensa que en tu caso `$row[0] = id`, `$row[1] = name` y `$row[2] = category`.

Te he agregado en el `while` un `fetch_array` donde en caso de que hicieras un `echo` de los registros podrías ver que indice tiene cada columna en el array.

Comment: En caso de alguna duda escribe un comentario!